# C++ Copy Constructor и Exceptions Handling

Tags: c++, исключения

Ниже приведен очень простой пример того как работает `copy constructor`:

```
class Base
{
  public:
    Base() { std::cout << "Base default constructor invoked!" << std::endl; };
    Base(const Base& copy) { std::cout << "Base copy constructor invoked!" << std::endl; };
    Base& operator=(const Base& copy) = default;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
    Derived() { std::cout << "Derived default constructor invoked!" << std::endl; }
    Derived(const Derived& copy) { std::cout << "Derived copy constuctor invoked!" << std::endl; }
};

int main(void)
{
   Derived der;
   Derived der0 = der;

   return 0;
}
```

И если в функции `main` изменить `Derived der0`, на `Derived& der0`, то `copy constructor` не будет вызван.

Отсюда появляется вопрос, почему когда мы отлавливаем исключения по ссылке:

```
try
{
   // throw error
} 
catch(std::exception& e) {}
```

Тогда у нас будет вызван конструктор копирования и при этом только для класса `exception`? 
Почему в обычной ситуации у нас (как в примере выше) не вызывается никакой конструктор копирования для класса `Base` когда мы выполняем `Derived& der0  = der`, но в блоке `catch` он вызывается, при этом только для исключения самого верхнего уровня?

Пример того как это работает, но без объяснения нашел [здесь](https://blog.knatten.org/2010/04/02/always-catch-exceptions-by-reference/).

Comment: Скорее всего это не `catch` копирует исключение, а `throw`.

Comment: `Derived& der0` - так это создание ссылки, тут никакие конструкторы не вызываются...

Comment: Не вижу проблемы. Программа создаёт сама объект класса `std::exception` , происходит простой конструктор и отдаёт вам ссылку. Где конструктор копирования?

Comment: @AlexGlebe как выше указал @goldstar_labs, при создании ссылки не ожидается вызов конструктора копирования. Если функция принимает параметры по ссылке, так же не ожидается вызов никаких конструкторов. Так почему же тогда, когда `catch` принимает исключения по ссылке этот конструктор вызывается? Чем параметр `catch` отличается от параметров функции в этом месте?

Comment: блин) там в примере говорится совсем про другое) если вы кинете объект наследного класса, а словите его по значению базового класса, то это приведет к ошибке, т.к. вызовется только конструктор копирования базового класса. Когда же вы ловите что-то по сылке (или указателю), то копирования не происходит вообще

Comment: естественно, что ссылаясь на объект ,  не хотим   копировать. В приведенной вами статье как раз об этом говорится, что  передавая по значению, копируется часть объекта наследника, поэтому лучше передать в блок по ссылке. Читайте внимательней и учтите, что не во всех статьях в интернете  не бывает ошибок...

Comment: @raviga, в вашем примере исключение ловят не по ссылке, а по значению, отсюда и происходит дальнейшая пляска с конструкторами

Comment: *"Так почему же тогда, когда catch принимает исключения по ссылке этот конструктор вызывается?"* - такие утверждения следует подкреплять приводя [mcve].

Comment: @goldstar_labs, я понял. сам себя запутал. спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На ссылке, что вы скинули рассматривается передача аргументов по значению и по ссылке на константный объект. В вашем примере вы показываете ссылку на действительный (имеющий адрес) объект (**не** константный). Ваш пример не такой.
   Аргументы функций вида `const &` принимают объекты любого типа (на временные или действительные). К конструктору копирования не имеют никакого отношения.

```
void f(int const & x) {
  ... }

void h(int & x) {
  ... }

void g(void){
  int x = 10 ;
  f(x); // Ok
  h(x); // Ok
  f(int(7.5)); // Ok

  h(int(7.5)); 
  // error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘int&’ to an rvalue of type ‘int’

  }
```